# Accessing previous theme variables in createMuiTheme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, theming, jss

Running **Material UI** `1.0.0-beta.24`

I'm setting a new theme using `createMuiTheme`:

```
import {createMuiTheme} from 'material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontSize: 16
  }
});

export default theme;
```

How can I access the theme I'm overriding directly here ? 
I'd like to do this, which is not working :

```
import {createMuiTheme} from 'material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontSize: theme.typography.fontSize + 2
  }
});

export default theme;
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You'd need to create an instance of the default theme and use it when defining your own:

```js
import { createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';

const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme();

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontSize: defaultTheme.typography.fontSize + 2
  }
});

export default theme;
```

Comment: is there any perfomance related issues with doing this at all?

Comment: This worked but I ended up with **a lot** of duplicate styles (not just overrides, but the exact same declaration). Maybe this would have cleared up in a build (I only tried during development), but the below answer from @zeckdude worked fine for me.

Comment: You could also use the new experimental [sx  syntax](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#the-sx-syntax-experimental). Although I can't figure out how to use it

Comment: @sayandcode You would still need access to the theme object to do this.  The `sx` prop for components supports a callback that accepts `theme` as its parameter, but this isn't the case with the experimental syntax for defining themes.

Comment: Anyone know how you might do this in v5 AND access component styles? Use case; I want to derive a margin based on the default theme InputBase margin and a style override I've applied elsewhere.

Answer (score 8):

You can also create your theme and then add on to it after `theme` is created.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from 'material-ui/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme();
theme.typography = {
  ...theme.typography,
  fontSize: theme.typography.fontSize + 2
}

export default theme;
```

Comment: This one will not work in different situations. For example, If you are passing the theme down to other components as the main theme using <themeProvider> then the default properties won't exist anymore. The example you used where you overwritten typography, some of the properties by default that were attached to typography aren't there anymore causing errors for components that rely on those variables. If you want to use just one default theme the solution provided above by Ken is more suitable.

Comment: You’re right. I have updated my answer to keep all the default typography properties and only overwrite the fontSize property. Thanks for the heads up.