# Use theme.spacing function in override in createMuiTheme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

Is there a preferred way to use the theme spacing when setting up the the theme with `createMuiTheme`? I've been hard coding these values and for the most part there hasn't been an issue since most of my projects don't override the default theme spacing, but it would be nice to be able to use the theme spacing in my overrides?

Comment: It is not the answer you need but it might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47977618/accessing-previous-theme-variables-in-createmuitheme

Comment: @ihist if I remember correctly this is basically what I ended up doing

Comment: @Jordan, if I understand correct what you want to achieve, the MUI documentation should help you: https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/spacing/ .


const theme = createTheme({
  spacing: [0, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64],
});

theme.spacing(2); // = '8px'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is resolved in the new Mui v5 by using a function passed to a style name

```
export default createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiAppBar: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: ({ theme }) => ({
          margin: theme.spacing(2)
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**TypeScript**

```js
import { Theme } from '@mui/material';

interface StyleOverridesParams {
  theme: Theme
}

export default createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiAppBar: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: ({ theme }: StyleOverridesParams) => ({
          margin: theme.spacing(2)
        })
      }
    }
  }
})
```

`ownerState`, "the combination of runtime props and internal states" for the component, is also available in the callback.

https://mui.com/blog/callback-support-in-style-overrides/